# Use Cauchy's Integral Formula (probably) to find the value of the integral

Tags: complex-analysis

Given $r>0$ and $a\in\mathbb{C}$ find:

$$I=\int_{|z-a|=r}{\frac{e^{2z}}{(z-a)^3}}dz$$

Given the section this exercise belongs to, it is not meant to be solved using the residue theorem.

Cauchy's Integral Formula states that if $f$ is analytic in $\Omega$ and $\gamma \subset \Omega$:

$$n(\gamma,a)f(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{z-a}dz$$

If want to turn $I$ into something that looks like it could be solved using CIF I think of:

$$f(z)=\frac{e^{2z}}{(z-a)^2} \Longrightarrow I=\int_{|z-a|=r}{\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)}}dz$$

With the obvious problem that $f(z)$ is not analytic inside $|z-a|=r$. So I'd appreciate any help and tips I get.

Comment: **Hint.** One possible thing is to use similar integral formulas you have probably shown for the values of higher derivatives of $f$ at $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Using [CIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula):

$$\oint_{|z-a|=r}\frac{e^{2z}}{(z-a)^3} dz=\left.\frac{2\pi i}{2!}\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\left(e^{2z}\right)\right|_{z=a}=4\pi ie^{2a}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Since $\frac1{(z-a)^3}=\frac12\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}a^2}\frac1{z-a}$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\int_\gamma\frac{e^{2z}}{(z-a)^3}\,\mathrm{d}z
&=\frac12\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}a^2}\int_\gamma\frac{e^{2z}}{z-a}\,\mathrm{d}z
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the power series expansion of $e^{2z}$ centered at $a$:

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^ne^{2a}}{n!}(z-a)^n.$$

On $|z-a|=r$ the sum converges uniformly, so integral and sum and can can be interchanged.